# Swift display annotations in mapView in another thread

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

This code does not add annotations to mapView. I saw in one answer that `mapView` function is called every time `addAnotation` is called so where's the problem? But when I move map they show up.

```
func addPlacesMarkers(location:CLLocation) {
    self.communication.getJsonData(self.getPubsNearByCreator(location)) { (finalData, error) -> Void in
        if error != nil {
            print(error)
        } else {
            if let row: NSArray = finalData {
                for var i = 0; i < row.count; i++ {
                    let lat = row[i]["lat"] as! String
                    let lng = row[i]["lng"] as! String
                    let title = row[i]["name"] as! String
                    let id = row[i]["id"] as! String

                    let point = CustomizedAnotation(id: Int(id)!, name: title)

                    point.title = title
                    point.coordinate.latitude = Double(lat)!
                    point.coordinate.longitude = Double(lng)!
                    let keyExists = self.places[Int(id)!] != nil
                    if keyExists == false {
                        self.places.updateValue(point, forKey: Int(id)!)
                    }
                }

                var finalPlaces :[MKPointAnnotation] = []

                for place in self.places.values {
                    finalPlaces.append(place)
                }

                self.mView.addAnnotations(finalPlaces)
                self.mView.showsPointsOfInterest = false
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't modify the UI in a thread different from the main.
You should put your UI modification code inside a dispatch_async block like this:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
    //Your code that modify the UI 
    self.mView.addAnnotations(finalPlaces)
}
```

Comment: thank you, worked for me. in few minutes I will accept.